# How to reproduce contingency of order in hstore?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

The documentation of PostgreSQL's key-value pair `hstore` states that

`"The order of the pairs is not significant (and may not be reproduced on output)."`

(see here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/hstore.html)

I've never experienced a mix up in the order of an hstore and thus wonder how and when it happens. I would like to understand why and when these non-guaranteed orders happen because sorting `hstore` can be costly.

Bonus question: Does anybody know whether this the case for `json` or `jsonb` data types, too?

Comment: The current implementation may never change the order, the docs just say that they're not guaranteeing that the order won't change and future implementations (if there are any) could reorder the keys to optimize access any other reason. I'd guess that the order could change by adding and removing keys but you'd have to spend some time reading the source code to be sure. The JSON specs say that ["An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs"](http://json.org) so you cannot expect any consistent ordering in `json` or `jsonb`. Perhaps you really want to use PostgreSQL arrays or JSON arrays.